# Can't commit local changes for certain files in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some local changes in a file, `.classpath` with respect to the remote repository. (Yes, I know I shouldn't have the classpath files in the shared repo, but that's a different story.)

This proves that there are some local changes:

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    PhotoFeed/.classpath
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

However, they don't appear in git status:

```
$ git status
# On branch release-1.5.1
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This file is not in *.gitignore*, as this commands proves:

```
$ git status --ignored
# On branch release-1.5.1
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .metadata/
#   PhotoFeed/.settings/
#   PhotoFeed/bin/
```

I've also tried to remove it from the `assume-unchanged`, but it doesn't change anything:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged PhotoFeed/.classpath
```

It can't be added to the staging area. I can do `git add -f` on it, but `git commit` keeps saying that there is nothing to commit.

How can I make this file be "normal" again? I want to be able to diff on it, commit it, or maybe just `git rm` it. That is, what other git config file/flag/property may be hiding this file?

Answer (score 1):

There is another git config file that is used to ignore files: `.git/info/exclude`

The difference between the files `exclude` and `.gitignore` is that the former is not versioned, is for your personal use. For instance, to *exclude* files from your IDE or your OS.

Comment: Good point (that I had not considered), but it still doesn't solve it: I don't have those files in `.git/info/exclude`, unfortunately

Comment: @espinchi is it possible that you share your repository?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's a product in development built within a private company.